# Insert value from javascript to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am making a type of slider form for restaurant management system in which user will select items in each form and the selected values will be displayed at last "confirm form" and i want to insert values of selected items obtained at confirm form to be inserted into database.

```
 <script>

    function changeColor(obj){
        obj.style.color = "red";
        var selected_val = obj.innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('target_div').innerHTML=document.getElementById('target_div').innerHTML+" "+selected_val;
    }

</script>


 <form id="formElem" name="formElem" action="" method="post">
            <fieldset class="step">
                <legend>Roti</legend>
                <?php
                $qu = mysql_query("select * from submenu WHERE menu_id=33") or die(mysql_error());
                while($f = mysql_fetch_array($qu)){
                ?>
                <p>
                    <label for="name" onclick="changeColor(this)"><?php echo $f['submenu']; ?></label>
                    <input id="name" name="name" type="hidden" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF value="<?php echo $f['id']; ?>"/>
                    </p>
                <?php } ?>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="step">
                <legend>Sabji</legend>
                <?php
                $qu2 = mysql_query("select * from submenu WHERE menu_id=34");
                while($f2 = mysql_fetch_array($qu2)){
                ?>
                <p>
                    <label for="name" onclick="changeColor(this)"><?php echo $f2['submenu']; ?></label>
                    <input id="name" name="name" type="hidden" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF value="<?php echo $f2['id']; ?>"/>
                </p>
                <?php } ?>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="step">
                <legend>Salad</legend>
                <?php
                $qu3 = mysql_query("select * from submenu WHERE menu_id=35");
                while($f3 = mysql_fetch_array($qu3)){
                ?>
                <p>
                    <label for="name" onclick="changeColor(this)"><?php echo $f3['submenu']; ?></label>
                    <input id="name" name="name" type="hidden" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF value="<?php echo $f3['id']; ?>"/>
                </p>
               <?php } ?>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="step">
                <legend>Sweets</legend>
                <?php
                $qu4 = mysql_query("select * from submenu WHERE menu_id=36");
                while($f4 = mysql_fetch_array($qu4)){
                ?>
                <p>
                    <label for="name" onclick="changeColor(this)"><?php echo $f4['submenu']; ?></label>
                    <input id="name" name="name" type="hidden" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF value="<?php echo $f4['id']; ?>"/>
                </p>
                <?php } ?>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="step">
                <legend>Confirm</legend>
                <p>
                    <label id="target_div" for="name"></label>

                </p>
                <p class="submit">
                    <button id="registerButton" type="submit" name="confirm">Confirm</button>

                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

I want to insert the value obtained at `confirm form` into database using `PHP`.

Comment: Since nobody knows what your database looks like, I doubt you will get much help. In general, the form posts to a script, in that script check what is posted by using: echo "<pre>".print_r($_POST,true)."</pre>"; From there, you need to construct some INSERT statement and run it on your database.

Comment: i want to just insert values obtained at "label" and i just want a simple insert string for that for example:-insert into test values("value of label");
but i dont know where and how to put this string to get values inserted

Comment: I'll answer in a normal posting because it doen't fit in here.

Comment: ok but kindly link me to that

Comment: I is posted. I told you it was too long to post as a comment. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the essential part:

```
           while($f = mysql_fetch_array($qu)){
            ?>
            <p>
                <label for="name" onclick="changeColor(this)"><?php echo $f['submenu']; ?></label>
                <input id="name" name="name" type="hidden" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF value="<?php echo $f['id']; ?>"/>
                </p>
            <?php } ?>
```

You repeat it for other categories (salas, sweets, etc), so let's look at that first.

And a few things are wrong with it.
First, your label says for="name". Name should be a UNIQUE identifier in the document. An identifier is an id="whatever". So if you want to target a specific element with your label, be sure to make the id="" match the for="".

In your case this is most easily done by adding a unique key from the underlying database-table.

But I cannot help because I cannot see your columns in the database. You use:

```
select * from submenu WHERE menu_id=33
```

Please stop using the lazy * and NAME the columns you need.
I hope you have a column that is the primary key in tblsubmenu. Let's say it is **id**. (I think a better name would have been submenuid.)

Then you can use that to do the labeling and id's right, like this:

```
            <?php
            $qu = mysql_query("select submenuid, submenu,  from submenu WHERE menu_id=33") or die(mysql_error());
            while($f = mysql_fetch_array($qu)){
            ?>
            <p>
                <label for="name<?php echo $f['id']; ?>" onclick="changeColor(this)"><?php echo $f['submenu']; ?></label>
                <input id="name<?php echo $f['id']; ?>" name="submenuid[]" type="hidden" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF value="<?php echo $f['id']; ?>"/>
                </p>
            <?php } ?>
```

That way you have matching for="" and id="", for example: in the label: for="name181" and an id="name181".

Also note I changed your input form-element, now it's name is "submenuid[]"

If you now post the form, you will receive an ARRAY in $_POST["submenuid"].

Print it out with:

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($_POST,true)."</pre>";
```

And see if it matches what you wanted to send.

If so, you can now start with inserting, for example:

foreach ($_POST["submenuid"] as $submenuid){
   $id = (int)$submenuid; // force it to be an integer
   $SQL = "INSERT INTO tblorders (submenuid, customerid) VALUES ($id, 111)";
   // execute here against database, see links below
}

[w3schools-link for starters](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp)

[PHP website mysqli.query.php](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)